# Using foreign key constrains to prevent update of parent row

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use foreign key constrains to prevent update of parent row when the index is in use by a child row?

Here is the schema of the parent table:

```
create table if not exists incident_options (
id int  not null auto_increment primary key,
idx int not null,
field int not null , 
value varchar(50));

ALTER TABLE `incident_options` ADD unique (`idx`, field);
```

And the child table:

```
create table if not exists incident_values (
optn int,
value varchar(1000));

ALTER TABLE `incident_values` ADD INDEX (`optn`);
```

Here is the constraint that I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE `incident_values` 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`optn`) REFERENCES `incident_options`(`id`) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Supposing I have the the following data:

```
incident_options
 __________________________
|id | idx  | field | value |    
| 1 |  0   |   1   | foo   |
| 2 |  1   |   1   | bar   |
 --------------------------

incident_values

 ______________
| optn | value |    
| 1    |  baz  |
 --------------
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to prevent 'foo' from being updated because the row is in use in `incident_values`

To update 'bar' would be fine

Here is the query I'm using to modify the row:

```
insert into incident_options (`idx`,`field`,`value`)
values ('0','1','test')
on duplicate key update
`idx` = values(`idx`),
`field` = values(`field`),
`value` = values(`value`)
```

At present 'foo' will be updated to 'test'

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible. Foreign key constrains only ensure that the keys are properly linked between the two tables, it has nothing to do with the other columns in the table.

Comment: Maybe you can do what you want with a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've set the constraint on the wrong table. You have put `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` on the `incident_values` table, but when you are doing the insert and update this is all happening on `incident_options`.

Unfortunately, you can't set this constraint inside the `incident_options` table because you may not always have a reference back to the `incident_values` table, so I do not think this is possible using a constraint. As Barmar mentioned in the comments, you may be able to implement a trigger in some way to preform verification before updating a field.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it was very helpful. would you mind checking out my own answer and let me know what you think?.

Comment: I think I'm going to have a go at setting up a trigger, my solution is surely  too nuts for it not to have some negative impact down the line

Comment: @andrew best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of hackery I did actually achieve what I wanted.

By forcing an increment of 'id' when 'value' has changed, the update of 'id' will not be permitted if there is a relationship

```
on duplicate key update
idx = values(idx),
field = values(field),
id = if(
        values(`value`)=`value`,
        id,
        (SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='incident_options')
        ),
values= values(value)
```

Though I'll see if there is any advice against using this solution before implementing it in my application

Comment: I'm no performance guru, so by no means do I have an authoritative opinion here but I like the idea. This worked when you tested it?

Comment: My concern is racking up the id column a bit too quickly, if there is no relationship and the value is modified the id will be incremented. I may have to think about using a bigint, but yes, it works